# Window freezing when not active using dotnetbrowser

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dotnetbrowser

I have searched around about this weird .NET WinForms application behavior and I couldn't find an explanation or a solution.
I have a From which has a dotnetbrowser (chromium) component that loads a page periodically and launch some scripts on it (which I can monitor using a loading label and a logger textbox), I launch a multiples instances of the program, after few minutes I find some of the instances blocked (freezes) sometimes at recreating the browser instance other times at loading a page.

The weird thing is that when I hover over the window I get the loading mouse pointer and when click directly on the window it's not responsive. but when I right-click on its icon on the taskbar the application becomes active and continue loading the page or recreating the browser component.

Does anyway have any explanation of what might causing the .NET application to go asleep when it's no the foreground, and any solution to prevent all instances of going dead after a while. (CPU usage not exceeding 40%, also I have enough RAM left).

Thank you folks

Comment: Intermittent application freezes can be related to the execution of long operations in the UI thread. 

You can try taking a process dump at the moment of freeze and analyzing it in Visual Studio.